# How to get Chinese Character String c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 strings which both of them have Chinese characters.

For example:
1) **你好嗎** / How are you?
2) How are you / **你好嗎**?

As you can see, I have 3 Chinese characters in different position. What I want to do is that I want to get only the Chinese characters out in these two strings. That's mean **你好嗎**.  Is there a way to do this? Help will be appreciated. Thanks

I have this function below

```
public string isChinese(string string){
    //Code to get chinese string??


    return string;
}
```

Comment: This does not help, I don't want the boolean value. I only want to get the Chinese characters '你好嗎'

Comment: The answer to that question states how to check if some text is Chinese, i.e. `text.Any(c => c >= 0x20000 && c <= 0xFA2D);`. You just need to apply that to *obtain* the Chinese characters of the string.